# What is unrolling in LSTM

Tags: lstm, keras

In keras LSTM if unroll set False does it mean that output of current timestep is equal to input next time step?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to build a computation graph. "Unroll" is a way to transform the recurrent calculations into a single graph without recurrence. This is a trade-off: faster processing, but consumes more memory. It's best for short sequences, which have low memory overhead.

I've found the text and diagrams in this blog post helpful: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

The [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/) says much the same.

> `unroll`: Boolean (default `False`). If True, the network will be unrolled, else a symbolic loop will be used. Unrolling can speed-up a RNN, although it tends to be more memory-intensive. Unrolling is only suitable for short sequences.